# How to control the page size when printing a page

Tags: html, css

How come the width of the browser affects the width of the print???

[image]

Look at this example - when the browser window is wide - the print becomes almost truncated to be wide as well

But when the browser is narrow, then the print looks great and fits the page.

How do I get it to do the same nice size in the print, no matter how wide the browser is?

(and no, max-width did not work, sure it did set the max width but the page just looked like this - so it didnt fix the problem)

[image]

Here is my printer CSS:

```
<style>
    @media print {
        body {
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
        @page {
            size: portrait;
            margin: 10mm 5mm 5mm 5mm;
            mso-header-margin:0mm;
            mso-footer-margin:0mm;
            mso-paper-source:0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: try: @page {size: A4;......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the iframe where I am putting the document inherits the CSS from the website itself.

As soon as I did this, everything worked...

```
//
// Render Document
//
var renderDocument = (html) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.write(html);
    document.close();
    resolve();
})};
```